# 3 tables (1 bridge) select where table 3 does NOT have an entry in table 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

That was a hard question to phrase. Let me clarify

```
Table 1: ID1  
Table 2: ID1, ID2  
Table 3: ID2
```

the ID is NOT a key, and can be NULL. Each table represents a station, so in the world, they enter in an ID1 of 19 at table (station) 2, then and ID2 there as well. It is then entered in at table (station) 3. 
For whatever reason they did not enter anything into table 1...maybe the line was going too fast.

Table 2 *Should* contain and entry to tie together each ID1 and and 2

```
ID1 = 19  -Table 1  
ID2 = 29  -Table 3
```

Table 2 should then contain an entry:

```
ID1 19, ID2 29
```

However, this is not always the case. sometimes ids are 'lost' in transit, like in the above example.

I would like to find a way that I could see if I could see any entries in table 3 that do not have a corresponding entry in table 1. so the result would look like:
ID1 = NULL  ID2 = 19 ID3 = 29

Comment: Some sample data and desired output would go a LONG way to making this answerable.

Comment: this is your basic interview question about left joins to find missing elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` paired with a `WHERE <value> IS NULL.`

```
SELECT ID 
FROM table_3 as three
INNER JOIN table_2 as two
 ON two.ID2 = three.ID2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_1 as one
 ON one.ID = two.ID1
WHERE one.ID IS NULL 
AND three.ID IS NOT NULL ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

> I would like to find a way that I could see if I could see any entries in table 3 that do not have a corresponding entry in table 1

I feel as if you're eluding to being able to do the following:

```
 SELECT * FROM table3 t3 
 LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t3.id=t1.id 
 WHERE t1.ID IS NULL
```

This is a pretty standard technique to find x missing from table y. Its also a common interview question.

You could also do this:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM table3 t3 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT id 
        FROM table1
        WHERE id = t3.id
    )
```